# Exception Code 0x40000015 in qt 5.4.2 - MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit

Tags: qt, dll

My Qt application cashed in a Windows 7 Professional.
Below you find the error log. It claims that the Module

> "C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110.dll"

generated the error but there is not the "MSVCR110.dll"  under the folder "C:\Windows\system32\"

> Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore:
>   AcuEurotherm_ReomoteControl_v15_n.exe, versione: 0.0.0.0, timestamp:
>   0x58f76312 Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: MSVCR110.dll,
>   versione: 11.0.51106.1, timestamp: 0x5098858e Codice eccezione:
>   0x40000015 Offset errore 0x000a327c ID processo che ha generato
>   l'errore: 0x1570 Ora di avvio dell'applicazione che ha generato
>   l'errore: 0x01d2b9cfd96f6768 Percorso dell'applicazione che ha
>   generato l'errore:
>   C:\Users\acucns\Desktop\EXPERIMENTAL_SW\Qt_projects\AcuEurotherm_ReomoteControl_app_Ver2\Qt_Exe_5-4_msvc2012_OpenGL\AcuEurotherm_ReomoteControl_v15_n.exe Percorso del modulo che ha generato l'errore:
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR110.dll ID segnalazione:
>   1c1acf45-2764-11e7-9be4-1866da10c3cf

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is your application cannot find the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from Visual Studio 2012.  You need to include these files in your release or have them installed on each system.  See this article from Microsoft on how to do this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299(v=vs.110).aspx