# My app crashed caused by ucrtbase.dll. What does it mean? Where should I look for bug in my code?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I use Qt 5.10.1 64 bit, msvc2017-64, all dlls from the redistributable package are included. It happened just once, I can not reproduce it.

> ```
> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
> Application Name: eyeblink.exe
> Application Version: 3.1.2.0 
> Application Timestamp: 5acb80c8 Fault
> Module Name: ucrtbase.DLL 
> Fault Module Version: 10.0.14393.2247 
> Fault Module Timestamp: 5adc1d0b 
> Exception Code: 40000015 
> Exception Offset: 000000000006eacf 
> OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
> Locale ID: 1051
> Additional Information 1: 53f4 
> Additional Information 2: 53f453b2107907ea889c32b664ccee74 
> Additional Information 3: c023
> Additional Information 4: c023e69e5a570b66998367aafd38badf
> ```

Comment: Googled ["Exception Code: 40000015"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Exception+Code%3A+40000015) and found [SO: Exception Code 0x40000015 in qt 5.4.2 - MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691092/7478597). Missing DLL due to missing Redistributable was my first idea also. Hence, I think it's worth to check this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception Code 0x40000015 in qt 5.4.2 - MSVC2012\_OpenGL\_32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674694/exception-code-0x40000015-in-qt-5-4-2-msvc2012-opengl-32bit)

Comment: I checked, thanks, I do not think its duplicate, It happened just once and all dlls are included